# go postgres refactoring pq CopyIn to pgx CopyFrom

Tags: postgresql, go, pq, pgx

I'm trying to refactor code so that I will connect to postgres DB using pgx, not pq.
I've tried a lot of things, but I keep getting the **ERROR: incorrect binary data format (SQLSTATE 22P03)**. Please find below both the original working code and my attempt at refactoring. What am I doing wrong?

```
// pq code
stmt, _ := txn.Prepare(pq.CopyIn(table, "id", "client_id", "channel_id", "feature"))
for _, user := range users{
    _, err = stmt.Exec(stringA, stringB, integer64, pq.Array(stringArray))
}

//pgx code
rows := make([][]interface{}, len(users))
ix := 0
for _, user := range users{
    rows[ix] = []interface{}{stringA, stringB, integer64, stringArray}
    ix++
}

_, err = txn.CopyFrom(context.Background(), pgx.Identifier{table},
        []string{"id", "client_id", "channel_id", "feature"}, pgx.CopyFromRows(rows))
```

EDIT: I got a hint from the pgx documentation: **CopyFrom requires all values use the binary format.**

The problem was my id (noted as stringA in the code above). It was created as:

```
stringA := uuid.New().String()
```

I augmented it with pgtype and now it works like a charm:

```
newStringA := &pgtype.UUID{}
_ := idPgtype.Set(stringA)
```

Comment: Can you show the table's SQL definition?

Comment: I'd prefer not to; it's pretty huge + it's corporate.

Comment: Just show the relevant code, i.e. the columns you're trying to copy from `(id,client_id,channel_id,feature)`. The types of those columns might be relevant to your problem. In general, if you're looking for help on SO, you should provide a [mcve].

Comment: You are right, I didn't give enough code. I'll edit the question to include the solution.

Comment: glad you fixed it, however,, the answer should be posted below, as an anwser. It should not appear within the question.